# Sarcoplasmic hypertrophy routine not working

Tags: muscle-mass, muscle-gain

I am working out from last 8 months and I have had significant improvement in mass gain as well as strength gain.
I was earlier focusing on strength with 3-4 sets of 5-6 reps with weights as heavy as I could lift.
I have gained 15 kgs including some dense muscle along with fat.

Now I would like to go for pure size and look more puffed up rather than having a dense look.
To accomplish the same I have started with high volume training(sarcoplasmic hypertrophy ) with 4-5 sets of 10-12 reps 
with moderate weights so that I can perform 10 reps.My diet is same as before(3600 cals and 200 g protein). The rest interval between sets now is about 90 secs.

I am following this new program for over a month and I don't see any progress in either weight or muscle size.
Could anyone suggest something?

Comment: I would try eating more. 200g is plenty of protein but 3600 calories is low for some people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first recommendation is for patience.  In particular, gaining mass at a rate that brings with it more muscle size than fat requires a good deal of patience.

- You should aim for an increase of 3 lbs/ month or 0.75 lbs per week.

  - If you see no change in mass, eat more food--particularly more carbs
  - If you see a change in mass that's too fast, eat less food
- You should strive for an increase in overall volume, while still managing recovery

  - 3 sets of 10-15 is great, and so is 10-15 sets of 3
  - If you hit 3x15 and can't do the work for the next increase at 3x10, trade reps per set for more reps (i.e. 5 sets of 5-10 reps, then 10-15 sets of 3 reps)
  - If you hit a wall with that, drop weight and add sets (i.e. 5 sets of 10-15)

The name of the game is progressive overload.  Being able to do a little more than you used to be able to do.  Volume is most important for hypertrophy.